# How to invert a series which has both integer and half integer powers

Tags: series-expansion

I have a series which has both integer and half integer powers.

$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{4}+\frac{x}{8}-\frac{x^{3/2}}{16}+\frac{x^2}{32}-\frac{x^
   {5/2}}{64}+\frac{x^3}{128}-\frac{x^{7/2}}{256}+\frac{x^4}{512}+O\left(x^{9/2}\right)$

I want to  invert this series using mathematica. When I use the command `InverseSeries`, it can not invert. Any suggestion how to invert this.

Comment: Are you looking for a series representing the inverse function of the above, or do you want to find the function that is represented by this series?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP a series representation.

Comment: How about letting $y:=x^{1/2}$ and using a regular Taylor series in powers of $y$?

Comment: Looks like `Series[1/(2 + Sqrt[x]), {x, 0, 4}]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks. Yes, it is.  I  want to invert a general series like this form, it is just an example. I think  AccidentalFourierTransform  has given a valid answer.

Comment: Yes, @rhermans code works on my machine too.